# How to mock an event like 'keypress' or 'keydown' in an AngularJS unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've looked at previous articles but they seem to be updated, and I've hit a brick wall. Can anyone help me find a solution?

I've got a directive that has some events `bind`. It's a credit card number filter, so it adds a space every 4 numbers to make it easier to read. I'm trying to test it in karma/jasmine by feeding it the number `5555555555554444`, and expect response for `$viewValue` of `5555 5555 5555 4444`, but can't find a way to trigger the event to fire.

I've tried `$setViewValue`, `$render()`, `$digest()`, and I've tried some of the solutions from StackOverflow (over a year old) but they don't seem to work.

Is the only solution to use jQuery? And if so, does that jQuery solution still work? I've been trying to do this without including jQuery into my unit tests.

A code sample of what I'm working with:

```
    elem.bind('keypress', parseKeyPress);
    elem.bind('keydown contextmenu', parseKeyDown);
    elem.bind('cut paste', parseCutPaste);

    var parseHandler= function (value) {
      return value ? returnNumbersOnly(value) : '';
    };
    ctrl.$parsers.unshift(parseHandler);
    ctrl.$formatters.unshift(parseHandler);
```

Thoughts?

Comment: did you try `elem.trigger`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `elem.trigger(...)` to emit those events as needed.

Comment: @BuildTester1 you can create a one with `angular.element`